# Django still shows home page rather than the page that I want

Tags: python, django

I am learning django now for the first time and I am a bit stuck at the start . Please help me out here.

I created a new project through django and created a blog page inside my project through terminal(cmd). Directory was also formed for both in my PC.
When I run the server, localhost also shows "Installed worked Successfully"(attached).

Now for the 2nd step was to include a blog page in there. So I have made changes in "views.py", "urls.py" in both Project and blog directory(attached).
Now as of the tutorial I am following, now when I run my local host, it should not show the same "Installed Successfully" page but rather should give Error 404 of page not found(attached). And in my address bar when I give "localhost:8000/blog", then it should show a blog page. But for me it still shows the "Installed Successfully" page.

I tried this twice separately, maybe I missed something but can't figure it out.

Thanks.

[image: Installed Successfully]
[image: views.py]
[image: urls-blog]
[image: urls-project]
[image: Error that should shown according to tutorial]

Comment: Post code as text, not as images.

Answer (score 0):

From your settings/urls.py change

```
path('blog/', include('blog.urls')
```

to

```
path('', include('blog.urls')
```

Answer (score 0):

you have added *blog/*  in your url. to browse
write in browser url
 `localhost:8000/blog/`

Or you can just remove blog word

```
path('blog/', include('blog.urls') 

path('', include('blog.urls')
```

then you can visit by `localhost:8000`